# Python - If WGET access denied then

Tags: python, wget

I am writing a python script that performs an os.system call to wget and attempts to download a file from a set location. At the point of execution it does not know if the server has HTTP-AUTH or not but will attempt a wget of the default page. If not successful it needs to then run some alternative code. I have seen this question in Bash but not in python.

if os.system("wget http://{}".format IP)

else
run other code

Comment: And what *is* your question, exactly?

Comment: what's your question? The code you pasted isn't valid python. Also, a system call to download a file is not the best way to do that in python.

Comment: use the `requests`-module.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - its my first post. I know the system call may not be the most effective but I am new to this world. My question is how do I have python inspect the wget response and check for a match. I would think that I need to look for the HTTP error code for an unauthorised attempt else it could accept it is fine

Comment: @crashoveride look up a tutorial on how to download a file with python. You can either use a lib (`requests`) or python builtins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess.run` to execute `wget` then use the `returncode` to determine if it was successful. So it might look like this:

```
output = subprocess.run(["wget", "http://..."])
if output.returncode == 0:
     < wget worked>
else:
     < wget did not work>
```

You will need to look up wget's return codes [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html)

For more info on the subprocess look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)